# php session cookie not stored

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have this php script in my header.php file, sending HTTP headers to a python script, and setting a GUID as a session cookie:

```
 <?php
  ob_start();
  function guid(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    }else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
                .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
                .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
                .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
                .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
                .substr($charid,20,12)
                .chr(125);// "}"
        return $uuid;
    }
  }
  $UA = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $REF = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $IP =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $GUID = guid();
  $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["name"]))
    setcookie('name',$GUID);
  //echo $UA;
  //echo $REF;
  //echo $IP;
  //echo $GUID;
  echo exec("python /var/www/html/oscommerce-2.3.3.4/header_sender.py -u '$UA' -r '$REF' -i '$IP' -c '$GUID' -p '$actual_link' 2>&1");
  ob_end_flush();
  ?>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that this generates a new GUID for every page load in the same session - the session cookie seems to be not stored.

What could the problem be?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't declare `session_start()`;

**EDIT :**

Since you're not using `$_SESSION[" "]` but instead `$_COOKIE[" "]`.

It seems like you don't define how long the cookie will be stored on your browser by `time() + x seconds`

```
setcookie('name',$value,time()+..);
```

Comment: Hi, should that matter? I'm not using php session utils, but setting an HTTP cookie manually. Why do I need to call `session_start()`?

Comment: oh you're right..btw then IMO there is a simply cookie not a session , where session has Session ID which is stored as Cookie

Comment: well, according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php, not setting the time means a session cookie - that should live as long as the browser is not closed. I'll take a look at using php session functions.

Comment: let me update my answer i shouldn't delete the previous one (instead of just letting it be ) it makes our conversation becomes not related to a session. XD

Answer (score 1):

When you want use session so first need you start in `session_start()`, it should function used in first line in page after start php tag because if you used in between or end or any other place it is occur error header already sent,this error occur reason is when you used `session_start()` function in between code and you leave any space between code so this error has occur

Answer (score 0):

Not the issue here, but my search for PHP cookie not setting lead me here so answering for anyone else that comes along.

Also pay attention to how you are setting expiry (if you are).  I originally was setting like this:

```
setcookie(self::$tokenCookie, $response['refreshToken'], 86400 * 365, "/");
```

The intent was to set it for 1 year in the future (86400 * 365).  However this makes it 1 year from epoch start (1970).  To get 1 year from *NOW* use this:

```
setcookie(self::$tokenCookie, $response['refreshToken'], time() + (86400 * 365), "/");
```

Kind of a duh moment, but it tripped me up and caused some frustration for a bit so hoping this will help someone else save that frustration.